# Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request.UserHostName throws ArgumentException in SignalR OnDisconnected handler

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, argumentexception

Calling `Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Request.UserHostName` inside my SignalR hub's `OnDisconnected` handler throws an `ArgumentException` with the message: "Value does not fall within the expected range." Why is that?

Comment: Are you using SignalR for ASP.NET or for .NET Core?  What version of SignalR are you using?  Do you check to see if `Context.Request.GetHttpContext()` or any of its components are null?

Comment: Do you ever set `UserHostName`?  Check if it is null in `OnConnected()` handler?  Mine is null in both places but I do not use it or set it.

Comment: @eglease It should be set by MVC.

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?  Does it work/get set anywhere else in your application?